# Do I need a pulldown resistor with a voltage follower?

Tags: voltage-measurement

As a school project we were given the task to build a remote controlled car. For monitoring the battery voltage, I chose to use a voltage divider with a voltage follower, as the battery has a voltage range of 9.9-12.45 V.

I am also measuring the voltage of the individual cells, as it is a LiPo Battery and when the voltage of one of the cells drops below 3 V it becomes chemically highly unstable. For clarification: the voltage of one cell could be below 3 V already, although rather unlikely while discharging, meanwhile the other two are at 3.6 V or something like that making the total voltage 10.2 V.

The circuit is as followed:
[image]
Do I need a pull-down resistor between a voltage follower and an analog input? If yes/no, why?

I would expect the answer to be "No, because the voltage follower has a common ground with the micro-controller so the voltage doesn't 'float'".

PS I am sorry if I was unclear about the voltage follower, but I thought it was clear that I would use an OpAmp IC for a remote-controlled-car.

Comment: A voltage follower isn't what an engineer would call "grounded" so, please post your schematic. Also provide details of the analogue input.

Comment: I'd upvote the question if the OP provided a schematic.

Comment: What kind of voltage follower it is? Why would there even is a need for voltage follower if the divider already outputs suitable voltage? Post the schematics.

Comment: I voted to re-open because the OP provided the schematics that explain the actual circuitry. And the voltage on each cell is being monitored, so the battery is obviously a Lipo type. Also, the ADCs apparently use a 5 V reference from the Arduino power supply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said a “voltage follower” which could be either an op-amp buffer or something like a BJT emitter-follower. The latter is addressed in other answers and makes little sense to me functionally, but I would say that it would depend on the nature of the input- if it has negative bias current or small positive bias current then an emitter follower might not work properly without a resistor. Very small differences in bias current could result in large voltage differences, especially if the E-B junction becomes reverse biased. But even the voltage change from +1nA to +100nA bias current is going to be hundreds of mV.

---

If it is an op-amp buffer (which makes a whole lot more sense) ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5GnAk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

... then a resistor to ground is probably not needed provided the op-amp output can swing all the way to the desired lowest voltage with the input as a load. Since your range is well offset from zero, that constraint is easily met. In some cases, a pull-up could be required. If you use an op-amp with rail-to-rail output and input, and don't demand the op-amp output get too close to either rail, then neither is likely required.

Comment: I had assumed an emitter follower. But reading directly from a voltage divider with an ADC, perhaps with a capacitor noise filter, should be sufficient for a 9-12 V battery monitor. Once you "graduate" to an op-amp, might as well add offset to get full range for the ADC.

Comment: Many application notes for LM324 say that having a 10k load will help the output go closer to 0V when needed. So I'd say it may not be needed, it will just make the circuit better.

Comment: @PStechPaul There's advantages to a higher resistance voltage divider (eg. less drain on the battery), and not all ADCs are happy with high input impedance. Some PICs specify < 2.5kΩ, for example. Easier to protect perhaps, too. If you can go directly in, that's generally better of course.

Comment: @Justme There is a nominal 50uA current sink in the LM324 so the resistor is less needed if the op-amp is required to sink less than (say) 20uA. With an LM324 and no zero offset I would be more worried about the top end since the range of interest is 9.9 to 12.45, so the natural tendency would be to put that near the top end of the ADC range.. and many ADC use the supply as reference, so, for example near 5.0V. So maybe you'd want a pull-up in that case to deal with the Darlington on the output (and give up the bottom 6-800mV). Or cheat and use a RRIO op-amp.

Answer (score 2):

This question really needs a schematic, which is probably why @AnalogKid disagrees with @Graham. Here is what I believe the OP (and Graham) have in mind for an emitter follower:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZei3y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Battery voltage divider and emitter follower]

I added the diode D1 to compensate for the B-E junction, and the voltage divider provides an output of about 2 V to 3.3 V for battery voltage from 9 V to 13 V. However, the emitter follower is really not needed. It may allow higher resistance for the voltage divider, but the ADC will still need a source impedance of 5k or less, so battery current drain will be the same.

I'll add an op-amp circuit that provides full range of 0 to 3.3 V from an 8 to 13 V battery:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAPmmI.png)</sup>

[image: Battery voltage monitor with offset for ADC]

For a battery voltage from 8 V to 13 V, the output to the ADC is 0 to 3.3 V.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the LM324 op-amp.

It does not have a rail-to-rail output as per modern standards, but it depends what output range you need.

Most LM324 application notes do say that if you want the output to go very near 0V, there should be a load resistor from output to ground.

If you don't need output near ground then you don't need a separate load either.

However, make sure that the op-amp output is stable when reading it with the ADC. The ADC input is very high impedance, but when it is taking a sample, it is switching a small capacitor to the pin to take a voltage sample. The LM324 output may not like it and it might be unstable. Usually op-amps can't handle switched capacitor loads well, especially at unity gain. It might be a good idea to have a series resistor or RC filter between op-amp output and ADC input.

Another thing to consider is if voltage divider is already used to bring down the voltage to suitable levels for reading with MCU ADC, what purpose does the op-amp voltage follower have and could it work without the op-amp.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is conceptual, I have used conceptual schematics below with suitable values.

## Emitter follower

If by "voltage follower" you mean "emitter follower"...

### External load connected

... the only case where an emitter "pulling" resistor may not be needed is when there is a load with some relatively low resistance (e.g., the ADC input resistance in your case).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwsfKi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see from the graph below, the output voltage follows the input one with a difference of several hundred millivolts.

[image: STEP 1]

### No load connected

If there is no something connected between the emitter and ground (open circuit), there are no base and collector current flowing...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faFwM7.png)</sup>

... and the output voltage is equal to Vcc.

[image: STEP 2]

### Extremely high load resistance

It is enough just to connect a 1 Gohm voltmeter...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnjMx4.png)</sup>

... and the circuit starts to function (the output voltage follows the input)...

[image: STEP 3]

### Leakages connected

... but this is an illusion because if there is a negligible 100 Mohm leakage between the output and Vcc...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu8UrD.png)</sup>

... the follower stops working again.

[image: STEP 4]

### Internal "pull-down" resistor

So there is a need of a relatively low resistance (e.g., 10 k) in the emitter...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUq8kv.png)</sup>

... and the leakages will be suppressed.

[image: STEP 5]

## Op-amp follower

Having clarified that the OP meant a voltage follower made via an op-amp (ie, an "op-amp follower"), here is a short follow-up to my answer.

> Do I need a pull-down resistor between a voltage follower and an analog input? If yes/no, why?

Connecting a "pull-down" resistor between the op-amp output and ground does not make any sense because inside the op-amp output stage there is such an element (PNP transistor).

> I would expect the answer to be "No, because the voltage follower has a common ground with the micro-controller so the voltage doesn't 'float'".

My answer is "No" but not because the voltage follower has a common ground with the micro-controller but because the op-amp output is a "voltage output" that does not need additional "pull-down" resistor (see my explanation above). If there was no common ground, adding a "pull-down" resistor would not solve the problem.

Comment: Good analysis. I would have thought that the voltage on the disconnected emitter would just track the base voltage through the diode junction, but perhaps the internal leakage causes the collector voltage to appear there. And once the emitter voltage exceeds that of the base, the diode becomes reverse biased and no current will flow. But it seems to take very little emitter current to restore the usual emitter follower behavior.

Comment: @PStechPaul, That was exactly the course of my reasoning! The transistor with a disconnected emitter is just a backward-biased base-collector junction and a very high resistance between the emitter and ground is sufficient to "pull down" the emitter to the "level" of the base. That's why, to show this phenomenon, I included the step with the almost ideal 1 Gohm voltmeter connected to ground and then with the 100 Mohm leakage connected to Vcc.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct that you don't need a pulldown resistor after the voltage follower. Pulldown (or pullup) resistors are useful to define the state of a wire when there is nothing driving that wire. In your case, the voltage follower will drive the wire at all times, so nothing to worry about.

Instead of a pulldown resistor, you might want to consider a series resistor or RC passive low pass filter instead. This will help remove any high frequency noise in your circuit giving you a cleaner measurement, and can protect the analogue input during first power on and in error conditions.

Comment: I upvoted to counter the downvotes, which should be explained. I am assuming an emitter follower is an NPN transistor with a load resistor to GND, and the ADC would read the emitter voltage, although it will drop about 0.7 V for B-E forward bias, and I really do not see a need for an emitter follower.

Comment: (Continue up- and down voting and see reputation rise for a zero score answer.)

Comment: But that would depend on how the follower is implemented. Which kind of follower you assume in your answer? A transistor? NPN or PNP? An op-amp?

Comment: Your explanations at the beginning about "pull-up" and "pull-down" resistors are valid for digital applications. Your thought that "the voltage follower will drive the wire at all times" is not true because the single NPN emitter follower is only a "pull-up" (sourcing) element. "To drive the wire at all times" it needs also a "pull-down" (sinking) element. Only the pair of two oppositely "pulling" elements can drive the "wire" (follower's output). This problem is solved in the best way in complementary ("push-pull") emitter followers.

Answer (score -1):

Strongly disagree with Graham.

With no pull-down resistance, the circuit output has two wildly different output impedances.  Assuming your emitter follower is an NPN transistor, when the output voltage is increasing the source impedance is the output impedance of the emitter follower, which can be calculated.  When the output voltage is decreasing, the source impedance can be infinite.

As the base voltage decreases, so does the emitter voltage.  With no reasonable pull-down resistance and a small amount of input capacitance at whatever is downstream, there is no discharge path for that capacitance.  The base-emitter junction can become reverse-biased.  At this point the output is essentially an open circuit, so whatever the input signal is doing is completely lost.

This is particularly bad when driving an A/D converter.  There are several different technologies used for this, and most of them "prefer" a low impedance signal.

Comment: (Then again, neither question nor [Graham's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/332616/graham) [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/667392/274544) mention *emitter* follower.)

Comment: Perhaps @AnalogKId could provide a schematic for what he envisions as a voltage follower that requires an additional pull-down resistor to avoid the issues presented in his answer. I have never seen an emitter follower without a pull-down or other load to GND.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why so many people assume an emitter follower. That would be a stupid solution when you want to measure the voltage accurately, and OP never mentions it.